# Was Jesus making a prophecy about the Zealots when he says "those who take up the sword will die by it"?

Tags: matthew, jesus, prophecy

So, shortly before his execution, during his arrest, Jesus tells one of his disciples the following:

> “Put your sword back in its place,” Jesus said to him, “for all who draw the sword will die by the sword.

(Matthew 26:52)

This was said in the context of the Roman occupation of Judea, where there were multiple religious sects; one of them, the Zealots, vigorously and violently opposed the Roman occupiers. Approximately 40 years later, that resistance eventually resulted in the extermination of their sect, the destruction of Jerusalem, and the diaspora of the Hebrew people.

Was Jesus prophesying these events in that moment? In addition to the literal meaning of the words in telling his followers to allow the Romans to arrest him, was he also saying, in effect, that those who joined the Zealots in taking up arms against the Romans would all be killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Was Jesus making a prophecy about the Zealots when he says "those who take up the sword will die by it"?**

Was Jesus making a prophecy? The answer is "No".

Caiaphas the High Priest sends soldiers during the night to arrest Jesus. During the meal with his apostle, he asked them to get two swords, obviously aware of his pending arrest.

Two swords.” And He said to them, “It is enough.”

Luke 22:36-38 NASB

> 36 And He said to them, “But now, [a]whoever has a money belt is to
> take it along, likewise also a bag, and [b]whoever has no sword is to
> sell his [c]cloak and buy one. 37 For I tell you that this which is
> written must be fulfilled in Me: ‘And He was counted with wrongdoers’;
> for that which refers to Me has its [d]fulfillment.” 38 They said,
> “Lord, look, here are **two swords.” And He said to them, “It is enough."**

Peter incensed by the injustice used the sword to cut the ear of someone in the mob, Jesus said to him.(Matthew 26:52)  “Put your sword back in its place,” “for all who draw the sword will die by the sword."

During the evening in his prayer, Jesus said that his followers are not part of the world.

John 17:16 NASB

> 16 They are not of the world, just as I am not of the world.

The next day during his interrogation  Jesus told Pilate:

John 18:36 NASB

> 36 Jesus answered, “My kingdom is not of this world. If My kingdom
> were of this world, My servants would be fighting so that I would not
> be handed over to the Jews; but as it is, My kingdom is not [a]of this
> realm.”

Jesus ruled out the use of force or violence by his followers against others, and that the fighting of injustice was to be left to God.

Comment: Yet Jesus came not to bring peace, but a sword. When He said "It is enough", it was because He had to let Himself be arrested, not because defending oneself is bad.

Comment: The sword Jesus speaks of is the "word of God". It's a symbol. "For the word of God is living and active sharper then a two edged sword. it penetrates even to dividing soul and spirit, joints and marrow; it judges the thoughts and attitudes of the heart'. He actually tells his apostles to "sell your cloak and buy a sword" in order to fulfill a prophecy that he would be numbered among the transgressors. He needed his disciples to take swords to fulfill this and become transgressors for prophetic reasons. It's why he admonishes Peter so harshly for actually using the sword.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is really just a more specific extension of the laws Jesus had already given. Of "reaping what you sow" or "doing unto others as you would have them do unto you". This the cornerstone of Jesus teaching. The "Golden law"

> In everything, then, do to others as you would have them do to you.
> For this is the essence of the Law and the Prophets.

By this law if you draw the sword to attack, kill and oppress others - then you yourself will be attacked killed and oppressed by the sword. Its not a prophecy specific to the Zealots - but it is a law that would apply to them. It applies to everyone.

Jesus teaches us essentially to do the opposite of this. To turn the other cheek and instead show mercy, forgiveness and grace to others. To pray for your enemy. And then mercy grace and forgiveness will also flow to us.